# How do you use GPIO output with RPi and Google Coder?

Tags: gpio, node.js, permissions, javascript

I am trying to set up the "[Blinky Lights](https://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder-projects/projects/blinky_lights/)" project with [Google](https://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder/) [Coder](http://hhttps://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/google-coder/) v0.9. I have used the code from the example project, unaltered, as well as setting up my breadboard exactly as the instructions describe. However, nothing works. I am getting an error that looks like

> SERVERLOG: "Could not write to pin: EACCES"

I have looked online, but haven't found anyone with a similar problem.

Could it have something to do with permissions? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I suppose someone will search for google coder and blinky lights.  For those of us that won't a few links would have been useful.

Comment: Are you running it with sudo? You need root access to get to the GPIO pins.

Comment: I have tried running it with sudo. I am aware that you need root access to use the GPIO pins, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: I have found a workaround by having Node.js from coder run shell scripts on the pi to change the pins, but I still can't do this using coder. It seems to be broken in the new build, and I haven't found a solution.